# how to stop unwanted debugging in chrome?

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I am having strange problem with chrome.

It is debugging my .js file even without break point. I don't know what the problem with my chrome.

**screen shot**

[image: chrome]

How to stop this unwanted  debugging of .js file of jquery in chrome please help.

I am using web services, so i want to count time to call those service but with this problem it does not show me a proper time duration.

Comment: Dont think if you stay on diffrenet tab like 'Network' or 'Element' it hits, Does it?

Comment: yes it hits even i am at other tabs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can See it stops on `try catch`. There might be exception.

You could have unknowingly enabled "pause on exceptions" option in the Scripts tab of the Developer Console.Its fouth from left . disable it and try.

Their indeed is exception statement which is `b!==c`

Found Useful content on http://forum.wakanda.org/showthread.php?2739-RPC-Example-%28Why-does-Chrome-debugger-stop-at-line-without-break-point-%29

This button appears at the bottom of the Debugger, and has 3-states. This allows you to choose one of the following actions:

1) black - don't pause for any exception.

[image: Dont Pause]

2)blue - pause on any exception, whether caught or not

[image: Pause On Exception]

3)red - pause only on uncaught exceptions

[image: Uncaught]

Answer (score 0):

For time measurement you can use chrome dev tools profiling feature. You can refer to the documentation here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline. I think this will solve your debugging problem also.

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger is set to break on all exceptions. See the small "pause" icon in the top right of the script tab. Currently, it will be blue. If you press it once, it will go to purple (break on uncaught exceptions). Press it again, it will go gray and it won't break at all.